# jQuery ready function for multiple drawings

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to use jQuery `ready` function for multiple ids so that they show and hide individually without writing the same type again and again. When I try to use it on the same line it opens all the drawings all together. The code looks something like this-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#p1','#p2', '#p3','#p4').hide();
  $('#p1-show','#p2-show','#p3-show','#p4-show').click(function(){
    $('#p1','#p2','#p3','#p4').show();
  });
  $('#p1-hide','#p2-hide','#p3-hide','#p4-hide').click(function(){
    $('#p1','#p2','#p3','#p4').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Using the `this` keyword targets the specific element you're clicking, if you want to toggle them individually. That way you can put them into classes without having to have a bunch of `id`s because it seems you're trying to use `id`s as classes.

Comment: As @ChavaG 's answer shows, multiple selectors should all be in a single string separated by commas, not multiple strings.

Comment: You need to share HTML code for better answers

Comment: As @GovindSamrow points out, without your HTML, we can only share answers based on a guess of what your code might look like...  However, you can use it to get an idea of what you need to do to make yours work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answers will work, but in case there are many such drawings then giving an #id to all those becomes badly repetitive and should be avoided. Following is a code snippet to make it more robust without much hard coded #ids.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(){
        var root = $(this).closest(".picture-container");
        var img = $(root).find("img");
        $(img).toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
body > div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="picture-container">
  <button class="toggle-btn">Show/Hide</button>
  <div>
     <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lggvvf2mCm1qgnva2o1_500.gif">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="picture-container">
  <button class="toggle-btn">Show/Hide</button>
  <div>
     <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lggvvf2mCm1qgnva2o1_500.gif">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="picture-container">
  <button class="toggle-btn">Show/Hide</button>
  <div>
     <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lggvvf2mCm1qgnva2o1_500.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you wish to keep all images hidden in the beginning then add the following line inside the ready function: 
$('.picture-container img').hide();

Answer (score 1):

Your function hides all of them.  If you want to hide the drawing based on which show/hide button is clicked, you can use `$(this)` to find the corresponding drawing.

The exact code will depend on how your elements are structured, but the idea is to use `$(this)` to target the element that was clicked, and from there find the element you want to hide.

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#p1, #p2, #p3, #p4').hide();
     $('#p1-show, #p2-show, #p3-show, #p4-show').click(function(){
          $(this).parent().find('p').show();
        });
     $('#p1-hide, #p2-hide, #p3-hide, #p4-hide').click(function(){
          $(this).parent().find('p').hide();
        });
    });
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="p1">First Drawing</p>
  <button id="p1-show">Show</button>
  <button id="p1-hide">Hide</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="p2">Second Drawing</p>
  <button id="p2-show">Show</button>
  <button id="p2-hide">Hide</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="p3">Third Drawing</p>
  <button id="p3-show">Show</button>
  <button id="p3-hide">Hide</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="p4">Fourth Drawing</p>
  <button id="p4-show">Show</button>
  <button id="p4-hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How about a link will show and a 'hide' link will hide an image?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need all of these selectors you have. It's overkill.

You should have your markup all the same for each 'drawing' it makes replication of this 'module' much easier for you also.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//this hides all of your <p> on page load
  $('p').hide();
  //this adds the click event to all the buttons with 'show'
  $('.show').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().find('p').show();
  });
  $('.hide').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().find('p').hide();
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <p>1st Image</p>
 <button class="show">show</button>
 <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>
<div>
 <p>2nd Image</p>
 <button class="show">show</button>
 <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>
<div>
 <p>3rd Image</p>
  <button class="show">show</button>
 <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>
<div>
 <p>4th Image</p>
  <button class="show">show</button>
 <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>
<div>
 <p>5th Image</p>
 <button class="show">show</button>
 <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>
```